# Apache Camel Pass Parameter

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, restlet

can any one let me know how I can pass parameter from "from" to "to".

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8080/processrequest")
    .process(inComingRequestProcessor)      
    .to("restlet:http://callservice.com?id=${id}")      
    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Data.class)
    .beanRef("httpServiceProcessor", "process").log("${body}");
```

I am getting id from localhost:8080/processrequest and want to pass same as query parameter.

Comment: Based on http://camel.apache.org/jetty.htmt, it says that the parameters are populated in Camel headers. So you should try `${header.id}`

Comment: I tried that whay by adding ${header.id}, however value is not passing to url. I am adding header in incoming request processor like exchange.getIn().setHeader("id", "123456");

Comment: ok, finally i managed to get header value as ${header.id}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the FAQ - there is somethings the answers :)

There is a FAQ about *dynamic to* which explains this and shows how to resolve it: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html